# Runtime error: Factor is exactly singular

Tags: python, runtime-error, fipy

I am trying to implement 2 **temperature models**, the following equations:

1. `C_e(∂T_e)/∂t=∇[k_e∇T_e ]-G(T_e-T_ph )+ A(r,t)`
2. `C_ph(∂T_ph)/∂t=∇[k_ph∇T_ph] + G(T_e-T_ph)`

#### Code

```
from fipy.tools import numerix
import  scipy
import fipy
import numpy as np
from fipy import CylindricalGrid1D
from fipy import Variable, CellVariable, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, Viewer, LinearLUSolver, LinearPCGSolver, \
    LinearGMRESSolver, ImplicitDiffusionTerm, Grid1D

FIPY_SOLVERS = scipy

## Mesh


nr = 50
dr = 1e-7
# r = nr * dr
mesh = CylindricalGrid1D(nr=nr, dr=dr, origin=0)
x = mesh.cellCenters[0]

# Variables
T_e = CellVariable(name="electronTemp", mesh=mesh,hasOld=True)
T_e.setValue(300)
T_ph = CellVariable(name="phononTemp", mesh=mesh, hasOld=True)
T_ph.setValue(300)
G = CellVariable(name="EPC", mesh=mesh)
t = Variable()
# Material parameters
C_e = CellVariable(name="C_e", mesh=mesh)
k_e = CellVariable(name="k_e", mesh=mesh)

C_ph = CellVariable(name="C_ph", mesh=mesh)
k_ph = CellVariable(name="k_ph", mesh=mesh)

C_e = 4.15303 - (4.06897 * numerix.exp(T_e / -85120.8644))
C_ph = 4.10446 - 3.886 * numerix.exp(-T_ph / 373.8)
k_e = 0.1549 * T_e**-0.052
k_ph =1.24 + 16.29 * numerix.exp(-T_ph / 151.57)


G = numerix.exp(21.87 + 10.062 * numerix.log(numerix.log(T_e )- 5.4))

# Boundary conditions
T_e.constrain(300, where=x > 4.5e-6)
T_ph.constrain(300, where=x > 4.5e-6)

# Source  (,) = ()−1 −/   , () =  exp (−2/2)/√22
sig = 1.0e-6
tau = 1e-15
S_e = 35

d_r = (S_e * 1.6e-9 * numerix.exp(-x**2 /sig**2)) / (numerix.sqrt(2. * 3.14 * sig**2))
A_t = numerix.exp(-t/tau)
a = (numerix.sqrt(2. * 3.14)) / (3.14 * sig)

A_r = a * d_r * tau**-1 * A_t 



eq0 = (TransientTerm(var=T_e, coeff=C_e) == DiffusionTerm(var=T_e, coeff=k_e) - G*(T_e - T_ph) + A_r

eq1 =(TransientTerm(var=T_ph, coeff=C_ph) == DiffusionTerm(var=T_ph, coeff=k_ph) + G*(T_e - T_ph)
eq = eq0 & eq1

dt = 1e-18
steps = 7000
elapsed = 0.
vi = Viewer((T_e, T_ph), datamin=0., datamax=2e4)


for step in range(steps):
    T_e.updateOld()
    T_ph.updateOld()
    vi.plot()
    res = 1e100
    dt *= 1.1
    while res > 1:
        res = eq.sweep(dt=dt)
        print(t, res)
    t.setValue(t + dt)
```

#### Problem

The code is working fine with very small `dt = 1e-18`, but I need to run it until `e 1e-10`.

With this time step is going to take very long time, and setting `dt *= 1.1` the resduals at some point start to increase then

gives following runtime error:

> factor is exactly singular

Even with very small increment `dt*= 1.005` the same issue pop up.
Using dt= 1.001 runs the code for quit long time then the residual get stuck at certain value.

#### Questions

1. I there any error in the fipy formalism of the equations?
2. What causes the error?
3. Is the error because of time step increase? If yes, how can I increase my time step?

Comment: With `dt*=1.1`, your `dt` values will get very large very fast,  Go compute 1.1**7000 to see that.  Which line gives you that error?  You have two competing definitions for `G`.  I don't see where `t` is defined.

Comment: sorry for that, one of Gs was comentted out in the code, however, even setting dt *=1.001 did not resolve the issue.

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error on line 61 --  a parenthesis is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @wd15's answer:

Your equations are extremely non-linear. You will likely benefit from [Newton iterations](https://gist.github.com/guyer/f29c759fd7f0f01363b8483c7bc644cb) to get decent convergence.

As @TimRoberts said, geometrically increasing the time step without bound is probably not a good idea.

I've recently posted a package called [steppyngstounes](https://github.com/usnistgov/steppyngstounes) that takes care of adapting timesteps. Although a standalone package, it's intended to work with FiPy. For example, you could change your solve loop to this:

```py
from steppyngstounes import FixedStepper, PIDStepper

T_e.updateOld()
T_ph.updateOld()

for checkpoint in FixedStepper(start=0, stop=1e-10, size=1e-12):
    for step in PIDStepper(start=checkpoint.begin,
                           stop=checkpoint.end,
                           size=dt):
        res = 1e100
        for sweep in range(10):
            res = eq.sweep(dt=dt, underRelaxation=0.5)
            print(t, sweep, res)
        if step.succeeded(error=res / 1000):
            T_e.updateOld()
            T_ph.updateOld()
            t.value = step.end
        else:
            T_e.value = T_e.old
            T_ph.value = T_ph.old

        print('elapsed:', t.value)

    # the last step might have been smaller than possible,
    # if it was near the end of the checkpoint range
    dt = step.want
    _ = checkpoint.succeeded()
    vi.plot()
```

This code will update the viewer every 1e-12 time units, and adaptively make it's way between those checkpoints. There are other steppers in the package that would facilitate taking geometrically or exponentially increasing checkpoints, if that kept things more interesting.

You could probably get better overall performance by sweeping fewer times and letting the adapter take much smaller time steps in the beginning. I found that no time step was small enough to get the initial residual lower than 777.9. After the first couple of steps, the error metric could probably be much more aggressive, giving more accurate results.

Comment: Thanks jeguyer , it is really interesting, I have been trying to install   steppyngstounes  since two days, unfortunately no success, I am using intellij, tried to add the package with pycharm also could not. I want to see if there is a difference in the results.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/usnistgov/steppyngstounes/issues/new) with details about the steps you've taken and the errors you get and we'll figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Dear Wd15 and jeguyer , I have another issue, I need to add a gaussian term to the variable C_ph at certain T_ph in order to include latent heat of fusion in the calculation. how can I do that?

Comment: Probably best to ask that as a new question, with some math describing what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks jeguyer, I just did , and about  steppyngstounes package, I could finally install using ubuntu, unfortunately to get good results I need to use very small dt 1e-12 is very huge I had to decrease it which raise the issue of calculation time. very great thank to you all.

Comment: please Wd15, and jeguyer help me with the other issue , Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185129/how-to-add-latent-heat-term-in-fipy

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few more changes to the code that can get you to an elapsed time of 1e-10. The main changes are

- Using `ImplicitSourceTerm` for the terms with `G`. This stabalizes the solution.
- Applied `underRelaxation=0.5` in the sweep step. This slows down the updates in the sweep loop so the feedback loop is damped down.
- Removed `FIPY_SOLVERS=scipy`. This isn't doing anything. `FIPY_SOLVERS` is an environment variable that you set outside of the Python environment.
- The way the boundary conditions were applied seemed strange so I applied them in a more canonical way.
- The sweep loop is fixed to 10 sweeps to get to a steady state quickly. Note that as the solution gets close to a stable steady state, the residual won't get better necessarily. Probably want to go back to residual checks if you need an accurate transient.

```
from fipy.tools import numerix
import  scipy
import fipy
import numpy as np
from fipy import CylindricalGrid1D
from fipy import Variable, CellVariable, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, Viewer, LinearLUSolver, LinearPCGSolver, \
    LinearGMRESSolver, ImplicitDiffusionTerm, Grid1D, ImplicitSourceTerm

## Mesh


nr = 50
dr = 1e-7
# r = nr * dr
mesh = CylindricalGrid1D(nr=nr, dr=dr, origin=0)
x = mesh.cellCenters[0]

# Variables
T_e = CellVariable(name="electronTemp", mesh=mesh,hasOld=True)
T_e.setValue(300)
T_ph = CellVariable(name="phononTemp", mesh=mesh, hasOld=True)
T_ph.setValue(300)
G = CellVariable(name="EPC", mesh=mesh)
t = Variable()
# Material parameters
C_e = CellVariable(name="C_e", mesh=mesh)
k_e = CellVariable(name="k_e", mesh=mesh)

C_ph = CellVariable(name="C_ph", mesh=mesh)
k_ph = CellVariable(name="k_ph", mesh=mesh)

C_e = 4.15303 - (4.06897 * numerix.exp(T_e / -85120.8644))
C_ph = 4.10446 - 3.886 * numerix.exp(-T_ph / 373.8)
k_e = 0.1549 * T_e**-0.052
k_ph =1.24 + 16.29 * numerix.exp(-T_ph / 151.57)


G = numerix.exp(21.87 + 10.062 * numerix.log(numerix.log(T_e )- 5.4))

# Boundary conditions
T_e.constrain(300, where=mesh.facesRight)
T_ph.constrain(300, where=mesh.facesRight)

# Source  (,) = ()−1 −/   , () =  exp (−2/2)/√22
sig = 1.0e-6
tau = 1e-15
S_e = 35

d_r = (S_e * 1.6e-9 * numerix.exp(-x**2 /sig**2)) / (numerix.sqrt(2. * 3.14 * sig**2))
A_t = numerix.exp(-t/tau)
a = (numerix.sqrt(2. * 3.14)) / (3.14 * sig)

A_r = a * d_r * tau**-1 * A_t



eq0 = (
    TransientTerm(var=T_e, coeff=C_e) == \
    DiffusionTerm(var=T_e, coeff=k_e) - \
    ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=G, var=T_e) + \
    ImplicitSourceTerm(var=T_ph, coeff=G) + \
    A_r)

eq1 = (TransientTerm(var=T_ph, coeff=C_ph) == DiffusionTerm(var=T_ph, coeff=k_ph) + ImplicitSourceTerm(var=T_e, coeff=G) - ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=G, var=T_ph))
eq = eq0 & eq1

dt = 1e-18
steps = 7000
elapsed = 0.
vi = Viewer((T_e, T_ph), datamin=0., datamax=2e4)


for step in range(steps):
    T_e.updateOld()
    T_ph.updateOld()
    vi.plot()
    res = 1e100
    dt *= 1.1
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        res = eq.sweep(dt=dt, underRelaxation=0.5)
        print(t, res)
        count += 1
    print('elapsed:', t.value)
    t.setValue(t + dt)
```

Regarding your questions.

> I there any error in the fipy formalism of the equations?

Actually, no. Nothing wrong with the formalism, but better to use `ImplicitSourceTerm`.

> What causes the error?

There are two source of instability in this system. The source terms inside the equation when written explicitly are unstable above a certain time step. Using an `ImplcitSourceTerm` removes this instablity. There is also some sort of instability in the coupling of the equations. I think that using under relaxation helps with that.

> Is the error because of time step increase? If yes, how can I increase my time step?

Explained above.

Comment: Very great Thanks wd15, I am very greatful to your help, the code works much smoother now and without problems. Is there a simple way to save the animation of the run as animation or vedio?

Comment: viewer.plot let's you dump to a file, https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/fipy/generated/fipy.viewers.html#fipy.viewers.multiViewer.MultiViewer.plot.